# How to add a select box value to a textbox?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, textbox

I mean, clicking on a value of selectbox this is added a textbox.
I do not know if you understand.

The language use: Javascript.

Please do not give me examples with jquery, thank you.

I wish you a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) and then `this.selectedIndex`, for example:

```
var selectBox = document.getElementById('mySelect');

selectBox.addEventListener('change', handleChange);

function handleChange()
{
    var selectedValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById('myInput').value = selectedValue;
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sPTU3/)

You may also need to support older versions of IE (i.e. < 11), so in that case you should also use [`attachEvent()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as follows:

```
selectBox.attachEvent('onchange', handleChange);
```